# How to can I query result control(if ,else) with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My code as below;

```
$stock_property_templates = StockPropertyTemplate::where('group_id' , 100)->where('type' , 'property')->get();
```

the following code is always output: here

```
if($stock_property_templates) {
            echo "have Data";
        }else {
            echo "do not Have Data";
        }
```

this code is working but I do not want it to work this way->  "[]"

```
if($stock_property_templates != "[]") {
            echo "have Data";
            return $stock_property_templates;
        }else {
            echo "do not Have Data";
        }
```

How can I write healthy code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`isNotEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-isnotempty) method to check if collection is not empty:

```
if ($stock_property_templates->isNotEmpty())
```

Or `count()`:

```
if (count($stock_property_templates))
```

Or:

```
if ($stock_property_templates->count())
```

Comment: if ($stock_property_templates->isNotEmpty()). Exactly as I want but not run empty() method . but why?

Comment: @ufuk oh yes, `empty()` will not work in this case because an instance of Collection is still returned. Use `isNotEmpty()`. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by 2 ways

**way one**

```
$stock_property_query = StockPropertyTemplate::where('group_id' , 100)->where('type' , 'property');
$stock_property_result = $stock_property_query->get();
if( $stock_property_query->count() == 0 ) {
  echo "do not Have Data";
} else {
  echo "Have Data";
}
```

**way two**

```
$stock_property_result = StockPropertyTemplate::where('group_id' , 100)->where('type' , 'property')->get();
if(count($stock_property_result) == 0) {
  echo "do not Have Data";
} else {
  echo "Have Data";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check for array `empty()`

```
if(!empty($stock_property_templates)) {
            echo "girdi";
            return $stock_property_templates;
        }else {
            return "girmedi";
        }
```